# Four iframes, two side by side

Tags: html, iframe

I have four iframes. I want them displayed as follows:

```
1 | 2
3 | 4
```

This is my code:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .box {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<html>
<p>
  <div class="box">
    <iframe src="webgl_sphereWithEquator.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="512" align="left">
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <iframe src="webgl_hopftorus1.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="512" align="right">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</p>

<p>
  <div class="box">
    <iframe src="webgl_sphereWithSlopedEquator.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="512" align="left">
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <iframe src="webgl_hopftorus2.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="512" align="right">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</p>

</html>
```

The `<p>` does not have the effect I expect. I get the four iframes on one line, side-by-side (each picture is an iframe):

[image]

How to "break" after two iframes ?

Comment: If you add your `clear` class to the third `.box` it will probably do it.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Yes!! I It works ! Thanks

Comment: No problem. Probably a good idea to get rid of the `p` tags as they should only really contain phrasing content and aren't doing anything anyway ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Hidden Hobbes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3400962/hidden-hobbes) stated in comments section, adding `clear` class along with third `box` class will do the trick, like:

```
<div class="box clear">
    <iframe src="webgl_sphereWithSlopedEquator.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="512" align="left">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Additionally, you can also do it by using the `box` class to the parent of the div where `iframe` present, like:

```
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <iframe src="webgl_sphereWithEquator.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="512" align="left">
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iframe src="webgl_hopftorus1.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="512" align="right">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div>
    <iframe src="webgl_sphereWithSlopedEquator.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="512" align="left">
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <div>
    <iframe src="webgl_hopftorus2.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="512" align="right">
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using Float and Width

CSS code

```
.box {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}
iframe {
    width:100%;
}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="box">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way would be to replace the `float: left` style with `display: inline-block`. Doing it this way, you could also get rid of the `.clear` class as well. What `float` is doing is it's getting rid of any proper "breaking" and making all elements "float", whether they belong there or not.

Also, I'd suggest changing your `<p>` tags to `<div>`, since they're acting as dividers anyway.

Edited CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .box {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
</style>
```